# Using boost::gil::color_converted_view with boost::gil::for_each_pixel

Tags: c++, boost-gil

I realized that writing to `gil::color_converted_view` doesn't affect the underlying view's data. I wonder if that's correct?

For example, let's say that I want to write a program that will take the value of the red channel and set the blue channel's value to half of that. Here's my failed attempt:

```
template <typename SrcView>
void half_red_to_blue(SrcView & view)
{
    // Since SrcView might be RGB or BGR or some other types,
    // I decided to use a color_converted_view to ensure that I'm
    // accessing the correct channels
    typedef gil::color_converted_view_type<SrcView, gil::rgb8_pixel_t>::type MyView;
    MyView my_view = gil::color_converted_view<gil::rgb8_pixel_t>(view):
    struct my_lambda
    {
        void operator()(gil::rgb8_pixel_t & p)
        {
            p[2] = p[0] / 2;
        }
    };
    gil::for_each_pixel(my_view, my_lambda());
}
```

However, it only works when `SrcView` is actually `gil::rgb8_view_t`. If I call, e.g. `half_red_to_blue<gil::bgr8_view_t>(view)`, the view is not changed at all! I inspected a little in the debugger and it seems the write operation is writing to some kind of proxy location instead of the original pixels.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is valid behaviour in Boost.GIL because the colour components of pixel are touched only upon access of pixel. You can modify my_lambda::operator() to use get_color to trigger colour component access.